# android - How to update the status multichoice items of alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application, I am displaying the alert dialog if you click on a button. The alert dialog consists of multi choice items and 2 buttons(i.e, Ok and Cancel). Initially I set some items using array(i.e., in code choice_checked).

1. If you open the alert dialog you did some changes and click on the ok button then dialog dismiss and  once again open the alert dialog then it shows the changes(i.e, this default property of alert dialog).
2. If you open the alert dialog you did some changes and click on the cancel button then dialog dismiss and  once again open the alert dialog in this case i want to show the previous status only(don't show the changes).i tried but i am not getting please can any body help me.
3. In the code choice_checked and choice_checked_dynamic are the boolean arrays.choice_checked_dynamic is the duplicate of  choice_checked. Means Initially these two arrays are same. If you did some changes in the list and click on the ok button then the changed array is copied into the choice_checked_dynamic. By default alert dialog shows the changes only so it is fine for ok button. But in case of cancel button, means if you did some changes then click on the cancel button then i want to display the  choice_checked_dynamic status(means i displayed the previous status ).

I tried but i am not getting please Can anybody help me.

Code:

```
private OnClickListener bookmark_btnListener = new OnClickListener()

{

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {                                   
             showDialog(DIALOG_MULTI_CHOICE);
        }
        catch(Exception ex2)
        {
            System.out.println("back btn error:"+ex2.toString());
        }
    }
};

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) { 
    case DIALOG_MULTI_CHOICE:                                        
         bookmark_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         bookmark_dialog.setTitle("Bookmarking for");
         bookmark_dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(choice, choice_checked, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index, boolean status)
             {                        

             }                  
         });

         bookmark_dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
           {                   
               for(int i=0;i<choice_checked.length;i++)
            {
               choice_checked_dynamic[i] = choice_checked[i];               
            }
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
         });
         bookmark_dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
           {   
               for(int i=0;i<choice_checked_dynamic.length;i++)
               {
                    choice_checked[i] = choice_checked_dynamic[i];              
               }              
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });
         return bookmark_dialog.create();         
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code problem is the dialog will be create only once using onCreateDialog() if you clcik on the button first time. The Next time onwards just dialog will be open no changes are applied. So i am not recommended the onCreateDialog() for this case. Here i am creating the dialog for every button click and show it.

```
// Code:
AlertDialog.Builder bookmark_dialog_obj;

private OnClickListener bookmark_btnListener = new OnClickListener()
{

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
    {                                   
        Bookmark_Dialog(RB_UpcomingRestaurantDetails.this); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex2)
    {
        System.out.println("back btn error:"+ex2.toString());
    }
}


public void Bookmark_Dialog(Context context) 
{

    System.out.println("onCreate Choice_Checked:"+Arrays.toString(choice_checked));                                  
    bookmark_dialog_obj = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    bookmark_dialog_obj.setTitle("Bookmarking for");
    bookmark_dialog_obj.setMultiChoiceItems(choice, choice_checked, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index, boolean status)
        {                     

        }                   
    });

    bookmark_dialog_obj.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
        {                      
            for(int i=0;i<choice_checked.length;i++)
            {
                choice_checked_dynamic[i] = choice_checked[i];               
            }            
        }
    });
    bookmark_dialog_obj.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
        {   
            for(int i=0;i<choice_checked_dynamic.length;i++)
            {
                choice_checked[i] = choice_checked_dynamic[i];              
            }      
            System.out.println("onCreate Cancel Choice_Checked:"+Arrays.toString(choice_checked));  
        }
    });
    bookmark_dialog_obj.show();         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **show()** instead of **create()** methode to show dialog and don't return created dialog at the end.

```
dialog.show();  
return null;
```

Activity do not sava state of dialog therfore dismiss do not work, but pressing the button dismiss multichoise dialog by itself or you can use deleteDialog(int id).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following method will fulfill your requirement.

```
protected void showMultipleChoiceItems(final String[] items,
        final boolean[] selections, String title,
        boolean cancelButtonDisabled) {

    Builder alertDialogBuilder = new Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);

    alertDialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, selections,
            new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    selections[which] = isChecked;

                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton(
            "OK", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    if (cancelButtonDisabled)
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    else
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(
                "Cancel", null);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    final Button btnOk = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            alertDialog.dismiss();
            onMultiSelect(items, selections);               

        }
    });
}

// Override this method in the activity to define action on making multiple
// selections
public void onMultiSelect(String[] items, boolean[] selections) {

}
```